# how to download file using interruptiblechannel? (NIO)

Tags: java, android

When I got an incoming call then I have to **immediately** interrupt my long running thread. I want to use Thread.interrupt() method to do that.

Reference says:

```
Threads blocked in an I/O operation of an InterruptibleChannel will 
have their interrupt status set and receive an ClosedByInterruptException. 
Also, the channel will be closed.
```

In my thread I'm downloading a file via HTTP, so I want to use InterruptibleChannel in order to immediately stop downloading. Could you give me some source code, how to download a file using InterruptibleChannel?

this solution is not okay for me, because Thread.interrupt() doesn't interrupt blocking IO:

```
while ((length = httpIn.read(buffer)) > 0) {
       if(Thread.interrupted())
          ....
       else
       {
            fileOut.write(buffer, 0, length);
            fileSize += length;
       }
}
```

Comment: now I can see how to download a file using NIO, but it doesn't use InterruptibleChannel:
https://github.com/rorist/android-network-discovery/blob/master/src/info/lamatricexiste/network/Network/DownloadFile.java#L50

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One general way to interrupt a thread that is blocked doing I/O is to close the channel. For example, if a thread is blocked in a read() operation over a socket, the thread that want to interrupt it can close the socket.
Not sure if this method will be useful for you, but its a general solution that some times it is used.